# Woocommerce all products become out of stock after import

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

We are having a very frustrating problem with Woocommerce import. We have class module and we just encountered this problem recently after several times of doing import without any issue. I have different csv files from different suppliers but almost have the same content which I use to import the products with no issue.

I have included the source code to check if someone out there could let me know if what are we missing here

thanks

This suppliers datafeed csv file: [feedfile](http://steepleit.co.nz/feed.zip)

Woocommerce Connector Class file is [connectorclass](http://steepleit.co.nz/classconnector.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this WordPress Free plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/ for import and export WooCommerce Products